# Two dynamic width divs in one line: one with ellipsis, second is close to first

Tags: css, html

Suppose, we have a list of groups, and the number of trainees per each group, like:

```
Math (34)
Physics (22)
Lingvo (33)
...
```

They're listed in the **JS** grid, and each renderer can be css-styled. Here is the problem: I need to display the list of groups so the numbers of trainees would be right the group name, but when the window is resized (made smaller), the number of trainees would stay on the right side of the column, but the long group name would be truncated with ellipsis, like:

```
|Math (34)
|Physics (22)
|Veerryy l..(18)
```

and even more:

```
|Math (34)
|Physics (22)
|Veerryy..(18)
```

When resized, those two divs (span) should not wrap one below each other. The min width of the grid is known, so eventually there will be a x-scroll.

Once the window size is restored, the group names will be displayed properly and the numbers of trainees will be still right the group name:

```
|Math (34)
|Physics (22)
|Veerryy long group name (18)
```

I expect this might be done with **CSS**, but tried a lot and still no success. I don't want to overload rendering in **JS**, so better stay with **CSS**. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float:right` to the number, and use `min-width` to title name with the use of `white-space:nowrap`, `overflow:hidden` and `text-overflow:ellipsis`.

**--EDIT--**

In addition, try using a `max-width` and `min-width` for the title. See the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/DxzuG/

...and you can always play with the width values to fit your needs.

Comment: For ellipsis it worked, but the numbers are still right-aligned in the column. They all should be closed to the group name.

Comment: Then instead of `float:right` you can use `position:relative` and `right:0`

Comment: If not using float, then the number div goes below the name div. I would also share the pic how I see this grid, but cannot post it until I have some reputation.

Comment: The number can stay inline if you use `display:inline` to both elements (title and number)

Comment: Still can't make that working. Created http://jsfiddle.net/FjZcV/. If you resize the window to smaller, you'll notice the second div wraps below.

Comment: Oh, that looks pretty nice, thank you, Otinanai! That is much closer to what I expect, good job!

Comment: if you're satisfied with my suggestion please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for ellipsis:

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
}
```